# 'gunicorn --paster' log messages not shown

Tags: pyramid, pylons, gunicorn, paster

I am starting gunicorn with the `--paster` option for running Pyramid.

```
gunicorn -w 1 --paster development.ini
```

gunicorn's own messages show up fine on console, for example

```
2014-02-20 22:38:50 [44201] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-02-20 22:38:50 [44201] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:6543 (44201)
2014-02-20 22:38:50 [44201] [INFO] Using worker: sync
```

However the log messages in my Pyramid app are not showing up.

If I use `pserve development.ini`, which uses `waitress` as WSGI server, the log messages show up on console just fine.

My `development.ini` includes a pretty vanilla logging configuration section.

```
[loggers]
keys = root, apipython

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_apipython]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = apipython

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = DEBUG
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

I am at lost why the logs are not showing up when I use gunicorn.

Comment: I tried it a different way, using `pserve development.ini` and changed `[server:main]` to `use = egg:gunicorn#main` - this works.  pserve uses gunicorn, and logs show up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use pserve with gunicorn, it is deprecated and most likely will be removed in some of the next versions.

Gunicorn has ["logconfig" setting](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#logconfig), just set it to your config via command line argument:

```
gunicorn -w 1 --paster development.ini --log-config development.ini
```

or in the same config:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
logconfig = %(here)s/development.ini
```

Comment: still doesn't work for me. I even tried setting up pyramid_exclog but that doesn't work either...

Comment: @julkiewicz how do you launch it? Latest gunicorn versions doesn't ever require `--log-config` anymore and use the same config provided with `--paster`. Either your gunicorn is quite old or there should be some error in your logging configuration

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of "pserve" command not only starts server and loads application, it also setups logging. While "gunicorn --paster" just loads application. To fix it you can explicitly setup logging on your application:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.paster import setup_logging

def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application. """
    setup_logging(global_config['__file__'])
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    # Configure application 
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Or as you pointed in comment, change server in config file and use "pserve" command:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
```